# Microphone not detected - Ubuntu 19.10, Laptop HP Envy 13, sound device Realtek ALC285

Tags: drivers, hp, microphone, realtek

I have just installed 19.10 (Kernel 5.3) on the HP Envy 13 laptop. Everything except the internal microphone works perfectly. The internal microphone is not detected at all. Is there any workaround?

my output from `lspci -v` regarding the sound card:

```
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 02c8
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 86ad
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 149
    Memory at b511c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at b5000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl, sof_pci_dev
```

My output from cat `/proc/asound/card0/pcm0c/info`

```
card: 0
device: 0
subdevice: 0
stream: CAPTURE
id: ALC285 Analog
name: ALC285 Analog
subname: subdevice #0
class: 0
subclass: 0
subdevices_count: 1
subdevices_avail: 1
```

EDIT: This is my alsa-info: http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=f786d8df6b4dd9bbcada3bdc22e1f59210187364

Comment: Can you try and add a screenshot of `alsamixer`?

Comment: @Yaron [link](https://i.imgur.com/2Bsv8Zr.png)

Comment: Same problem on 2019 HP Spectre x360, possible same as https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2414086&page=2&s=ec08dc25e1fcd7cf62e725fd1e160fbc

Comment: I have same issues with my HP Omen 17 2019 :/

Comment: @user10627948 any update on this? I have same issue with dell vostro 5391. For now my best found was this patch in alsa to add the PCI ID https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/10932285/

Comment: Seems like the mic is working on Ubuntu 20.04 beta. Had the same problem with 19.10 on HP Envy 2019 17".

Comment: I reported this today on Launchpad, as I have the internal mic problem for last 9 months with this codec ALC285. If you have the issue please select there that you are affected: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1892714